# C# OpenFileDialog is not showing Network location or mapped drive

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using C# OpenFileDialog in winforms .net 3.5 app to browse files, but unable to see mapped network location, my code is as below:

```
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        ofd.InitialDirectory = desktop;
        ofd.Filter = "Word 97-2003 Documents (*.doc)|*.doc|Word 2007 Documents (*.docx)|*.docx";
        System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtFilepath.Text= ofd.FileName;
        }
```

I am using Win7 OS.

Comment: Is your program running as administrator? Drive mappings get "lost" when you elevate a program.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with C# or Winforms.  Try it from Notepad's File + Open for example, same dialog.

Comment: Running as admin, tried notepad's File -> Open and can see mapped network drive there but it's not showing through my application.

Comment: I don't have admin rights, and I literally pasted your code to one of my projects and I can see (and select) files from my mapped drives. I'm also using Win7 (Pro).

Comment: Observed this on Windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. I think I figured it out or at least a part of it.

Network locations are created by user. Meaning if user "Jeff" creates a network location, only he will see the network location when trying to open a file through a program.

**For example:**

Our user "Jeff" opens notepad and tries to open a file through the notepad interface (File>Open). He will then be able to see the network drive and open any file he wants to.

If our same user "Jeff" opens notepad as administrator (meaning it opens as another user) and tries to open a file. He will not be able to see the network locations. (Of course you can navigate to the server in both cases by using \\servername\mapname etc)

**Possible solutions I found**

**Solution 1:**
[Forcing windows to make the network drives available to standard and administrator acounts](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f0073f80-cedb-4b7a-96b9-20e4b22c2424/folderbrowserdialog-does-not-show-network-drives-on-windows-8?forum=windowscompatibility):

1 - run regedit

2 - locate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

3 - create a new DWORD entry with the name EnableLinkedConnections and value 1.

4 - restart your computer

5 - now you can see and use network drives with these installers or applications.

**Solution 2:**
[Making sure every user gets the network drives added as soon as they login:](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84a89d4e-7a2e-4b5b-9ab6-68c68cabf3e0/map-network-drive-auto-connect-for-all-users?forum=winserverManagement)

Adding a script with the following lines

```
net use e: /delete
net use e: \\myserv\myshare
```

in the folder: "\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp" for all users.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

fbd.Description = "Custom Description";
fbd.SelectedPath = <A path to your mapped drive>;
```